# Spring API Rest - Creating new Custom Controllers and Registering in the /info

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I've create a simple controller in my Spring Rest service:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableEurekaClient
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/composite")
public class CompositeController {

  @Autowired
  private Composite composite;

  @RequestMapping(path = "/{name}")
  public ResponseEntity<Composite> getComposite(@PathVariable String name)
          throws Exception {
    this.composite.populateData(name);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.composite);
  }
}
```

But, when I call `localhost:{port}/info`, the new endpoint is not registered there.

How can I also include my new custom controller in the `/info`?

---

**Edit**

I am using Eureka Discovery Service, and when I register a new service with Eureka, the URL of the service is being returned as `localhost:{port}/info`.. My assumption was that I am doing something wrong since `/info` is returning an error.

Comment: Are you using spring security module in your project?

Comment: Shouldn't the correct URL be `localhost:{port}/composite/info` ?

Comment: yes it will be localhost:{port}/composite/info

Comment: But does it give security prompt like asking for username or password

Comment: updated my question further up...